# iOS UITableview similar to contacts app

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to replicate the contacts application in iOS, using two table views in the "New contacts" view. I am trying to scroll up the tableview when the keyboard covers the content. Each cell contains a textfield, I have to enter into that some details. I have used two table views, one is placed as header view over the other. I am not getting the code to scroll up the tables... Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want the 2 tableviews scroll together you have to use only one main tableview, I mean, you have a main tableview with all the content, and then cells with the textfields.

The cell with the photo, name, surname and enterprise (I'm not sure if they are the correct names because I have it in spanish), contains a imageview for the photo and a tableview with 3 cells, one for the name, other for surname and other for enterprise.

Comment: ya i want both tables to scroll together is there any method for that my table 1  is the main table and table 2 is hearview of table 1..juz i want to scroll the tables  when the keyboard hides textfields to enter..thanks for the response